# Maven: Property to stay the same for all modules?

Tags: maven, properties

I have a property in root pom.xml:

```
<foo>${basedir}/src/test/xslt</foo>
```

In a submodule, this gets re-evaluated, so ${foo} is different value in submodule.

How can I ensure that the value will be the same for all submodules? (Without hard-coding of course)

**Update:** Seems like there's no such feature. I'd suggest to have this added to Maven:

```
<foo recompute="false">...</foo>
```

Comment: ${project.parent.basedir} will give you base directory of the parent module.  It is possible to use that?